# How do I specify multiple libs directories in my ant script?

Tags: android, ant

I have a project that contains two library directories. For project organization reasons, these directories must remain separate.

```
<master project>
- libsA
-- android-support-v4.jar
- libsB
-- other-stuff.jar
```

In my ant.properties file I have set
jar.libs.dir=libsA;libsB

However, this doesn't work. My question is, how do I include two libs directories in my build?

Answer (score 0):

If directories have a common rootdir :

Use blank as separator in your propertyfile

```
jar.lib.dir=libsA libsB
```

Create path with id

```
<path id="foobar"> 
  <dirset dir="${root.dir}"/>
    <include name="${jar.libs.dir}"/>
  </dirset/>
</path>
```

and use path via id, f.e.

```
<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${dist}" classpathref="foobar"/>
```